# How do I change the width of mat-checkbox?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm having a hard time changing the width of mat-checkbox. It seems to stop at the end of the mat-checkbox label and doesn't extend further. I need it to extend to length of 630px. Is there a way to make it larger? I've tried numerous ways like width: 630px !important; width: 100% !important; max-width: 630px !important; max-width: 100%; width: auto !important but nothing seems to work.

```
<mat-checkbox
  (change)="setSelected(i)"
  [class.is-correct]="option.selected && option.correct"
  [class.is-incorrect]="option.selected && !option.correct">

  <mat-checkbox-label>
    <span>{{ i + 1 }}. {{ option.text }}</span>
  </mat-checkbox-label>
</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
 // Checkbox label width will be 630px
 ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-label {
    width: 630px;
 }
```

or

```
// Checkbox component width will be 630px
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox  {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 630px;
}
```

Comment: The second approach seems to work better (doesn't extend outside the mat-card like the first approach). I also need the height to be adjusted to 55px.

Comment: `::ng-deep .mat-checkbox  {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 630px;

    .mat-checkbox-label {
      line-height: 55px;
    }
}`

Comment: Ok got it, just had to modify the height on the mat-checkbox. Thank you very much!